# html5 nav element for multilanguage links

Tags: html

Should I include links to the same page on other languages inside nav?

Example (we are on Page1):

```
<nav>
<a href="page1">Page1</a>
<a href="page2">Page2</a>
<a href="page3">Page3</a>
<a href="page4">Page4</a>
<div class="flags">
<a href="/es/page1">Spanish</a>
<a href="/it/page1">Italian</a>
</div>
</nav>
```

Or it's better to put flags outside nav?

Answer (score 0):

Semantically you should put flags outside the nav.
They are not part of it, it's not an element of navigation but a link to the same page with other language.